# What is the boot(start) process of the Docker container?

Tags: docker, boot, lxc

I'm studying about Docker.

As I know, there are difference between Docker Container and OS in booting process.(Booting process of Docker container doesn't contain kernel execution)

I think this is how the Docker container starts.

1. Use libcontainer to call directly api such as cgroup, namespace, etc.
2. Execution of Linux container features
3. Creating RW Layers
4. Integration of image layers and RW layers with unionFS
5. Container connection via shell

However, I can't find more detail process. There are not any official documents or accurate reference that explain exactly this process.

Please let me know if there are any sites or documents that have organized the Docker start(boot) process.

Also, if you know about this, please advise.

Comment: Why not just read https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/create.go#L30 and https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/daemon/start.go#L18?

Comment: There's some details that I've found over here: http://docker-saigon.github.io/post/Docker-Internals/ but it doesn't directly address the question.

Comment: Thank you for your question. But I know that cgroups, namespaces, and other technologies are being used. However, I wonder how each of these functions is executed in order and creates a container.